# flask_restful - TypeError: Object of type Record is not JSON serializable

Tags: python-3.x, flask-restful

I try to provide a custom object inside a rest api, created with `flask_restful`.

#### Object: Record

```
import json

class Record():
    #CLASS RECORD
    def __init__(self, DateTime, DateTimeText, Status, Icon, Temp):
        #INITIALIZE
        self.DateTime = DateTime
        self.DateTimeText = DateTimeText
        self.Status = Status
        self.Icon = Icon
        self.Temp = Temp

    def __repr__(self):
        return json.dumps(self, default=lambda o: o.__dict__, sort_keys=False, indent=4)
```

#### Result: print(record)

```
{
    "DateTime": 1583949600,
    "DateTimeText": "2020-03-11 18:00:00",
    "Status": "Clouds",
    "Icon": "04n",
    "Temp": 280.57
}
```

#### Rest API:

```
from flask_restful import Resource, Api, reqparse    

class _Weather(Resource):
    #WEATHER
    def get(self):
        #GET WEATHER
        return {'value': Weather.Record}

self.Api.add_resource(_Weather, '/api/weather')
```

---

#### Error:

all other calls works fine, only me custom object (`http://localhost:80/api/weather`) returns the following error stack:

```
File "C:\Users\Martin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2463, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Users\Martin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2449, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\Martin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\flask_restful\__init__.py", line 272, in error_router
    return original_handler(e)
  File "C:\Users\Martin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\flask_cors\extension.py", line 161, in wrapped_function
    return cors_after_request(app.make_response(f(*args, **kwargs)))
  File "C:\Users\Martin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1866, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\Martin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 38, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Users\Martin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2446, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\Martin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1951, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\Martin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\flask_restful\__init__.py", line 272, in error_router
    return original_handler(e)
  File "C:\Users\Martin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\flask_cors\extension.py", line 161, in wrapped_function
    return cors_after_request(app.make_response(f(*args, **kwargs)))
  File "C:\Users\Martin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1820, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\Martin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 38, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Users\Martin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1949, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\Martin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1935, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "C:\Users\Martin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\flask_restful\__init__.py", line 472, in wrapper
    return self.make_response(data, code, headers=headers)
  File "C:\Users\Martin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\flask_restful\__init__.py", line 501, in make_response
    resp = self.representations[mediatype](data, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Martin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\flask_restful\representations\json.py", line 21, in output_json
    dumped = dumps(data, **settings) + "\n"
  File "C:\Users\Martin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\json\__init__.py", line 234, in dumps
    return cls(
  File "C:\Users\Martin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\json\encoder.py", line 201, in encode
    chunks = list(chunks)
  File "C:\Users\Martin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\json\encoder.py", line 431, in _iterencode
    yield from _iterencode_dict(o, _current_indent_level)
  File "C:\Users\Martin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\json\encoder.py", line 405, in _iterencode_dict
    yield from chunks
  File "C:\Users\Martin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\json\encoder.py", line 438, in _iterencode
    o = _default(o)
  File "C:\Users\Martin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\json\encoder.py", line 179, in default
    raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
TypeError: Object of type Record is not JSON serializable
```

I try a lot of different approaches, found here on stack. Non of these works for my.

```
Python 3.8.2
```

Comment: Did you try jsonify ?

Comment: Yes I do: `return {'value': jsonify(Weather.Record)}`, same error: _Object of type Record is not JSON serializable_

Comment: if it doesn't work you , can you try this package https://flask-marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of options here.

1. Make a tojson() method for your Record class and call that for your return value. It will basically just return the underlying `__dict__` for your object.

```
def tojson(self):
    return self.__dict__
```

2. Pass `Weather.Record.__dict__` directly as your return value

So your return statement will look like one of these:

`return {'value': Weather.Record.__dict__}`

Or, using jsonify from Flask:

`return jsonify({'value': 'Weather.Record.__dict__})`

Or replace Weather.Record.__dict__ with Weather.Record.tojson() if you add that method to the class.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I try all 4 alternatives. The only one that works for me was: `jsonify({'value': Weather.Records[0].tojson()})`, but the result is different from other calls. The result is `{
  "value": "{\"DateTime\": 1583960400, \"DateTimeText\": \"2020-03-11 21:00:00\", \"Status\": \"Clouds\", \"Icon\": \"04n\", \"Temp\": 281.95}"
}` and I think that the `"` before `{` should not correct or?

Comment: I have updated my answer. You are correct, it was returning a string representation of json, not a json/dict object that is needed for jsonify.